# ListView com config.properties

Tags: android, listview, bundle

Estou com uma seguinte dúvida, estou usando uma `listview` com uns 300 personagem de um jogo, ao clicar em um personagem ele insere alguns dados que está escrito no `config.properties`, todos os personagens tem descrições, vocações dentre outras informações diferentes.

O código está funcionando corretamente, mas minha duvida é o jeito que estou fazendo para inserir os dados não deixara o código muito pesado? Tem outro jeito mais correto?

Código:

**Util.java**

```
    public class Util {
    public static String getProperty(String key, Context context) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();;
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("config.properties");
        properties.load(inputStream);
        return properties.getProperty(key);

    }
}
```

**IvysaurActivity.java**

```
     @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ivysaur);
        //mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Toolname);
        mToolbar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Toolname);

 Number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Number);
        Level = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Level);
        Valornpc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Valornpc);

  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            mToolbar.setText(bundle.getString("TituloPokemon"));

            if (mToolbar.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Bulbasaur")) {

                try {
                    Number.setText(Util.getProperty("Number",getApplicationContext()));
                    Level.setText(Util.getProperty("Level",getApplicationContext()));
                    Valornpc.setText(Util.getProperty("Valornpc",getApplicationContext()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            if (mToolbar.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Venusaur")) {

                try {
                    Number.setText(Util.getProperty("Number2",getApplicationContext()));
                    Level.setText(Util.getProperty("Level2",getApplicationContext()));
                    Valornpc.setText(Util.getProperty("Valornpc2",getApplicationContext()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**config.properties**

```
Number=Teste1
Level=240
Valornpc=28.000;


Number2=Teste2
Level2=540
Valornpc2=58.000;
```

Desde já grato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que isso não possui uma resposta "correta", vai muito de testes e como você deseja criar seu banco de dados e a finalidade de sua aplicação. Por exemplo:

- Se for somente para mostrar dados e estatísticas dos pokémons. Pode usar uma abordagem menos complexa. Talvez até assim como está fazendo.
- Um jogo offline. Precisa se assegurar de possíveis mudanças nas propriedades de cada personagem por usuários mal intencionados.
- Um jogo multiplayer (online). É necessário uma abordagem bem mais complexa, segura e externa. Servidores, web services, autenticações, etc.

Considere que são somente exemplos e que há vários fatores envolvidos. Mas aí vai algumas dicas.

Se você possui um arquivo `.properties` para cada pokemon e suas evoluções, aí te garanto que não seria a melhor opção, pois você teria uma quantidade exorbitante de arquivos. Nesse caso, seria melhor deixar todos seus pokémons em somente um `.properties`;

Você deve levar em conta que esse arquivo pode ser **alterado** por qualquer um caso esteja salvo localmente (o que pode influenciar em sua aplicação dependendo do objetivo).

---

Uma alternativa um pouco mais segura seria criar um banco `SQLite` local. É a forma android mais "padrão" para aplicativos que necessitam salvar dados localmente, mas deve-se levar em conta o tamanho do banco, para não ocupar um espaço muito grande no dispositivo do usuário.

[Um tutorial de exemplo.](http://fabrica.ms.senac.br/2013/06/criando-e-usando-banco-de-dados-em-uma-aplicacao-android/)

---

Outra alternativa, que talvez seja a mais segura porém mais complexa, é criar um banco de dados em um servidor que se comunica através de um web-service, onde este se comunica com a sua aplicação. Isso deixa a aplicação totalmente livre de se preocupar com armazenamento, ela apenas realiza requisições ao web-service que por sua vez retorna os dados. É bem mais seguro também.

Exemplo comunicação android com servidor `php` e banco `MySQL`:

[image: Exemplo Comunicação]

Comment: Entendi, como faço para salvar o .properties em outro lugar sem ser localmente?

Comment: Você precisa de um servidor web. Você salva o arquivo nele e depois acessa via HTTP ou FTP pelo seu código. Ex HTTP: `URL url = new URL("http://seuservidor.com.br/config.properties");` Mas isso já é assunto para outra pergunta.

Comment: Zulian, legal a explicação. +1